# In my Lambda@Edge origin request function, the "event" parameter is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have a Cloudfront distribution with a default behavior and the following function association:

```
origin request: Lambda@Edge / arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:...:function:*functionName*:4
```

I can see the CloudFront trigger in the triggers tab in my lambda function version 4:

```
Event type: origin-request
Include Body: Yes
Path pattern: *
Service principal: replicator.lambda.amazonaws.com
Statement ID: replicator.lambda.GetFunction
```

My function's code looks like this:

```
'use strict';


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("context: ", context);
    console.log("event: ", event);
```

I made a GET request to my Cloudfront distribution using the Distribution domain name and this is what I found in the logs using the AWS CLI:

```
2023-04-18T20:50:37.021Z    e52078b4-2efa-40a8-9a28-51ed50ac0132    INFO    event:  {}
```

How can the event be empty here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a two-fold answer.

1. I was reading the logs in the wrong region (`us-east-1` while my execution region was `us-east-2`), and the empty event log did not  come from a proper execution of my lambda@edge function (I am not sure where they came from, maybe the initialization of the function).
2. I hadn't given the Lambda function the proper permissions to write and create logs in CloudWatch, and thus none were being produced. After adding those permissions and re-triggering my function, I was able to see the correct logs in `us-east-2` and the `event` argument was properly passed.

To allow the lambda function to create/write logs, I had to add the `AWSLambdaEdgeExecutionRole` role to it (under `lambda/configuration/permissions/execution role -> edit`), which should look like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```